# Inverting a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to invert the dictionary below but I keep getting an error that says `builtins.TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

```
input_dict = {
   1: ['hi', 'there', 'fred'], 
   2: ['there', 'we', 'go'],
   3: ['fred', 'was', 'there']}
```

Here's what I tried to do

```
def make_index(words_on_page):
    """Invert the dictionary"""

    inverted = {}
    for index, word in words_on_page.items():
        if word in inverted:
            inverted[word].append(index)
        else:
            inverted[word] = [index]
```

Can anyone please point out where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to iterate the words corresponding to the keys, like this

```
input_dict = {
    1: ['hi', 'there', 'fred'],
    2: ['there', 'we', 'go'],
    3: ['fred', 'was', 'there']
}


def make_index(words_on_page):
    """Invert the dictionary"""
    inverted = {}
    for index, words in words_on_page.items():
        for word in words:
            if word in inverted:
                inverted[word].append(index)
            else:
                inverted[word] = [index]
    return inverted

print(make_index(input_dict))
```

**Result**

```
{
 'fred': [1, 3],
 'go': [2],
 'hi': [1],
 'there': [1, 2, 3],
 'was': [3],
 'we': [2]
}
```